# Set inventorySubsidiary and inventoryLocation by line

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to send a sales order to NetSuite where the inventoryLocation and inventorySubsidiary (line level fields) are pre-defined. You can see where I defined it on the header, where it does work but this does not do anything to the line item fields inventoryLocation and inventorySubsidiary.

I tried to define it within the item parameters, as you see below, but I get errors like

**com.netledger.schemabean.NLSchemaBeanException: inventoryLocation not found on {urn:sales_2016_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com}SalesOrderItem**

I was looking at the documentation for Inventory Detail but it doesn't give a specific example of how to include this on a sales order line, it just says it can be used for sales orders. Do I need to use a wrapper like inventoryDetailJoin on each line? Somehow?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3744760.html

```
<soap:Body>
        <add xmlns="urn:messages_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <record xsi:type="q1:SalesOrder" xmlns:q1="urn:sales_2016_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q1:entity type="customer" internalId="$#AccountTSANSIntIDReal#$"/>
                <q1:memo>$#Remark#$</q1:memo>
                <q1:tranDate>$#ActionDateTime#$</q1:tranDate>
                <q1:customForm internalId="100"/>
                <q1:memo>$#Remark#$</q1:memo>
                <q1:subsidiary internalId="30"/>
                <q1:location internalId="202"/>
                <q1:itemList>
                    <q1:item>
                        <q1:item type="inventoryItem" internalId="1234"/>
                        <q1:quantity>"3"</q1:quantity>
                        <q1:inventoryLocation internalId="202"/>    
                        <q1:inventorySubsidiary internalId="30"/>   
                    </q1:item>
                  <q1:item>
                        <q1:item type="inventoryItem" internalId="5678"/>
                        <q1:quantity>"10"</q1:quantity>
                        <q1:inventoryLocation internalId="202"/>    
                        <q1:inventorySubsidiary internalId="30"/>   
                    </q1:item>                                                                                
                </q1:itemList>
            </record>
        </add>
    </soap:Body>
```

Comment: Just want to add when a line item is added to a sales order directly in NetSuite, the fields populate automatically -- but they don't populate when I send via SuiteTalk.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this worked for me once I changed

core_2018_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com to

core_2020_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com

```
 <q1:item>
                        <q1:item type="inventoryItem" internalId="5678"/>
                        <q1:quantity>"10"</q1:quantity>
                        <q1:inventoryLocation xsi:type="q1:RecordRef" type="location" internalId="202"/>
                        <q1:inventorySubsidiary xsi:type="q1:RecordRef" type="subsidiary" internalId="30"/>        
                    </q1:item>
```